# Как вывести ArrayList на экран

Tags: java, arraylist

Такой код(тут только то, что касается моего вопроса):

```
List<Track> tracks = new ArrayList<Track>();
String abbr = sc.nextLine();
String number = sc.nextLine();
String type = sc.nextLine();
String unit = sc.nextLine();
String frequency = sc.nextLine();

tracks.add(new Track(abbr, number, type, unit, frequency));
for (Track s : tracks)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

Мне нужно, чтобы выводилось содержимое, а выводится, вроде бы, ссылка(могу ошибаться, поправьте, если не так).
Вывод:
Track@35fb3008

Подскажите, что не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Track // .... {

   // Fields && || Methods
   // ......

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return new StringBuilder("Track{")
                 .append("abbr: ").append(abbr).append(",")
                 .append("number: ").append(number).append(",")
                 .append("type: ").append(type).append(",")
                 .append("unit: ").append(unit).append(",")
                 .append("frequency: ").append(frequency).append("}")
                 .toString();
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Переопределите метод toString в классе Track

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Track{" + "abbr=" + abbr + ", number=" + number + ", type=" + type + ", unit=" 
            + unit + ", frequency=" + frequency + '}';
}
```

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev 
спасибо за ответ! Теперь выводится содержимое, но вместо моих значений появляется null,  я так понимаю, класс не видит того, что вводится? Подскажите пожалуйста, хочу разобраться, что как происходит

Comment: @Vqq50 вам ответил JavaJunior, я только исправил форматирование в его ответе.

Comment: Значит поля вашего класса пустые, вернее null. А что происходит, вы просто переопределили метод родителя Object, который в сыром виде возвращает имя класса плюс его хеш код, что не совсем понятно описывает его.

Answer (score 1):

Выводите поля с помощью геттеров:

```
tracks.add(new Track(abbr, number, type, unit, frequency));
for (Track s : tracks) {
     System.out.println(s.getAbbr());
     System.out.println(s.getNumber());
     System.out.println(s.getType());
     System.out.println(s.getUnit());
     System.out.println(s.getFrequency());
}
```

или, если у вас в классе `Track` нет геттеров, замените это на прямые обращения к полям:

```
tracks.add(new Track(abbr, number, type, unit, frequency));
for (Track s : tracks) {
     System.out.println(s.abbr);
     System.out.println(s.number);
     System.out.println(s.type);
     System.out.println(s.unit);
     System.out.println(s.frequency);
}
```