# ArrayList. Как вывести данные из коллекции, типом данных которой является класс

Tags: java

Проблема в том что метод `get()` выводит не значения, а ссылку на них.

**Класс принимающий данные:**

```
public class Order {
    private int cost;
    private String name;

    public Order(int c, String n){
        name = name;
        cost = cost;
    }
}
```

**Объявление коллекции:**

```
ArrayList<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Вывожу так:**

```
System.out.println(orders.get(0));
```

**Output:**

```
Order@70177ecd
```

Как вывести все элементы ArrayList'а и получить правильный вывод?

Comment: правильный - это какой?

Comment: переопредели метод toString() у класса

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Назначение метода toString()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/592316/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-tostring)

Comment: Еще больше похожий вопрос: [Как вывести ArrayList на экран](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/837873)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Чтобы output был `нормальный` необходимо переопределить метод `toString()`. В вашем случае он может выглядеть примерно так

```
public class Order {
    private int cost;
    private String name;

    public Order(int c, String n){
        name = name;
        cost = cost;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Order: { name = " + this.name + ", cost = " + this.cost + "}";
    }
}
```

Чтобы вывести все элементы, достаточно передат в output просто объект листа
    `System.out.println(orders);`, потому что у `ArrayList` ( а точнее у `AbstractCollection`) [переопределен](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/jdk/file/c5d02f908fb2/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#l453) метод `toString()` таким образом, что вызывается метод `toString()` у каждого элемента из этого листа

Answer (score 2):

Переопределите метод toString для вашего объекта так, как вам хочется, и должно заработать как вам хочется. Если окажется недостаточно, делайте сами вызов toString

```
System.out.println(orders.get(0).toString());
```

Comment: Если окажется недостаточно, то `toString` не поможет :)

Comment: Я имел в виду, что print должен вызывать от выводимого объекта toString и его можно не писать, но чет я в этом не уверен, потому добавил такое странненькое уточнение)